# Running script as root when connected as oracle user with ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a problem with my situation that i have to run a script inside another machine as `root`. **I can only do ssh without password as** `oracle`, so i have to write something like that:

```
  su - oracle -c "ssh $node /tmp/x.sh"
```

How can i run `x.sh` as root?

**EDIT**

```
[root@alz1 ~]# su - oracle
[oracle@alz1 ~]$ su
Password: 
su: incorrect password
[oracle@alz1 ~]$
```

Comment: You are root initially, change user to oracle, and then try to change back to root again?  Why?  Nowhere do you connect to a remote machine.

Comment: Because i can only ssh with oracle. Also i need to run my command as root

Comment: Yes, but you also need to connect to the remote box somewhere.  See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
su - oracle -c "ssh root@$node /tmp/x.sh"
```

Comment: I doesn't work because when i can only ssh to another node as oracle. When i ssh to other node with oracle, then run as root, it wants password.

Comment: If you can't ssh in as root, you need sudo access or the root password.  If you have neither of those, you need to talk to the administrator of the machine you are trying to do this to.

Comment: I have root password but how can i ssh with password in script ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to store the root password in a script.  Can you not ssh in to the oracle user interactively, and then run `su - -c /tmp/x.sh`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could set up passphrase-less keys to let your remote oracle user access the remote root user without needing to type anything.  This would make the oracle user equivalent to root on the remote box, which may not be desireable.

Comment: To the "no, it still wants a password": Well, yes, but you say you have this password.  Just type it?

Comment: It doesn't accept root password when i try it with su - root. Also how can i give password parameter with su - root line?

Comment: If you do `su - root` on the remote machine, and it does not accept what you type, you apparently don't have the root password. Also, `su` doesn't accept the password in a parameter, you need to type it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[root@box1]# su - oracle
[oracle@box1]$ ssh box2
[oracle@box2]$ su -
```

Then type the password for root at the remote box.  It should then proceed as

```
[root@box2]# /tmp/x.sh
```

and you're done.

Comment: i can connect with putty as root to machine but not with "su -" command, that's strange. what if i get the right password, how can i set password when running from script?

Comment: You don't want the root password stored in a script.  You can set up ssh to allow access without having to type anything by using keys with no passphrase.  Google for "ssh passphrase-less root access" will give you some pointers.